# color inicial del edittext en Android

Tags: android

En mi aplicacion estoy usando EditTextPreference para solicitar al usuario que ingrese una dirección IP, pero en el archivo XML en valor inicial es defaultValue="192.168.1.0" y esta con un fondo color celeste como pueden ver en la imagen, yo necesito cambiar el color solo de este texto inicial y el fondo, alguien me puede decir como hacerlo en el XML?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
    <EditTextPreference
      android:defaultValue="192.168.1.0"
      android:digits="0123456789."
      android:inputType="number|numberDecimal"
      android:key="example_text"
      android:maxLines="1"
      android:selectAllOnFocus="true"
      android:singleLine="true"
      android:title="IP Address" />
```

Comment: En realidad no es un EditText, es un EditTextPreference, es un poco diferente principalmente porque este último carga en una Activity de preferencias, saludos.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para cambiar el color al seleccionar el contenido del `EditText` o `EditTextPreference` usa la propiedad `android:textColorHighlight` y define el color deseado:

```
android:textColorHighlight="#00ff00"
```

para cambiar el color del texto usa la propiedad `android:textColor`:

```
android:textColor="#0000ff"
```

---

De acuerdo a el ejemplo anterior, el color al seleccionar el texto es verde y el color del texto sería azul:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]